# I want to use podSpecPatch to patch volumeMounts, but workflow will be failed

Tags: argo-workflows

I create a cluster workflow template, one parameter is `volume-mounts`. So I can choose already created pvcs to mount on the pod instead all of them.

Then I will get `spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "${volume-name}"`, but `${volume-name}` has already define in workflow `spec.volumes`

### demo

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterWorkflowTemplate
spec:
  templates:
  - name: main
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: volume-mounts
        default: "[]"
    podSpecPatch: |
      containers:
      - name: main
        volumeMounts: {{inputs.parameters.volume-mounts}}
    volumes:
    - name: data1
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: already-created-pvc1
    - name: data2
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: already-created-pvc2
```

```yaml
# params
volume-mounts: [{name: data1, mountPath: /data}]
```

Comment: Putting `{{inputs.parameters.volume-mounts}}` in quotes seems like it's probably a mistake?

Comment: Yes, but this is the demo error.
But `{{inputs.parameters.volume-mounts}}` not in quotes still go wrong.

Comment: yeah I encountered the same with a test Workflow with an emptyDir volume... I feel like it must have something to do with the order in which the pod spec is constructed by Argo. They monitor the Argo-workflow tag, but you’ll probably get a faster response if you open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

For continuity:

The Argo team is already aware of this and there is an issue open to this effect: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/4623